# Mongoose middleware cascading delete

Tags: mongoose

```
router.delete('/users/profile', auth, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // this returns Query object.
        // can I make it return a Document somehow???
        await User.deleteOne({ _id: req.user._id });

        res.send(req.user);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send();
    }
});
```

```
// I have set document to true and query to false but still the value of 'this' is a Query.
// I need this to be a document. Should I use something else instead of 'deleteOne' hook??

userSchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }, async function (next) {
    console.log(this);

    next();
})
```

Basically I'm trying to cascade delete some entries after a user is deleted. I'm stuck with the delete middleware. How do I get userSchema.pre() to give me access to a document inside it instead of a Query??? If I need to make changes to my router code then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. But i'm not sure how it is working. I'll share my solution below and I would be grateful if anyone can explain the reason behind why its working properly.

```
router.delete('/users/profile', auth, async (req, res) => {

    try {
        //this is how i'm getting the value for req.user. Just keep in mind that it's using User.findOne() which returns a Query.        
        //const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decodedToken._id, "tokens.token": token });
        const user = req.user;
        
        //deleteOne() is being called on a Query object
        user.deleteOne();
        
        res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send();
    }
});
```

```
// Notice that I have set document to true and query to false.
// I should be receiving the value of "this" as a Query object because deleteOne() was called on a Query object, however, it's value is a Document!!! I don't understand why this is happening.
userSchema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }, async function (next) {
    const user = this;
    
    await Task.deleteMany({ owner: user._id });

    next();
});
```

All in all the cascading delete functionality I was aiming for is working perfectly. If anyone understands why my code is functioning the way it is then please explain it.

Comment: User.findOne() is a query but it returns a document, which you assigned to const user. That is why user.deleteOne() triggers document middleware.